# Incorrect syntax near '.' SQL INSERT c#

Tags: c#, mysql, sql, sql-insert

I am trying to add new record to the SQL Database Table using class Object. I create a list of Products and then iterate through all of them with sql statement.

My code is like this:

```
    private void backupButton_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        ReadAllProductsList dbproducts = new ReadAllProductsList();
        DB_Product = dbproducts.GetAllProducts();
        List<Product> SQLProductList = new List<Product>();
        SQLProductList = DB_Product.Where(Product => Product.UserId == currentUser).ToList();
        for(int i = 0; i < SQLProductList.Count; i++)
        {
            InsertSQLProduct(new Product(SQLProductList[i].UserId,
                                                        SQLProductList[i].Name));

        }
    }

    public void InsertSQLProduct(Product objProduct)
    {
        using (var connection = new SqlConnection("Server=localhost\\SQLEXPRESS;Integrated Security=SSPI;database=MyLocalDB"))
        {
            connection.Open();
            using (SqlCommand command = new SqlCommand("INSERT INTO Product (UserId, Name) '" +
                                                        "'VALUES (null, '" + objProduct.Name + "');", connection))
            {
                command.ExecuteNonQuery();
            }

        }
    }
```

And the Product class looks like this:

```
public class Product
{

    // List<DietId> Lst = new List<DietId>();
    //The Id property is marked as the Primary Key  
    [SQLite.Net.Attributes.PrimaryKey, SQLite.Net.Attributes.AutoIncrement]
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string CreationDate { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }




    public override string ToString()
    {
        return Name;
    }

    public Product()
    {
        //empty constructor  
    }

    public Product(string userId, string name)
    {
        UserId = userId;

        CreationDate = DateTime.Now.ToString();

        Name = name;

    }
}
```

However, I get error on command that says:

> syntax error near '.'

What am I doing wrong here?

PS. The Name in SQL is of VARCHAR type.

EDIT:
I have used parameter and converted the string to varchar and now I get different error:

> String or binary data would be truncated.
>   The statement has been terminated

OK. Sorted.

The last error tells me that the column was accepting only 1 character as 1 is default for VARCHAR.

I recreated tables with new max input for records.

Using parameters has solved my original problem.

Thank you guys.

Comment: Parameterize your sql. Don't concatenate it together. You also have some strangely placed single quotes

Comment: I will, I am writing without parameters for testing.

Comment: Have a look at this [little bobby tables](https://www.xkcd.com/327/) as well

Comment: Test with parameterized queries though. They fix a lot of problems that concatenation causes. They are also JUST as easy to write. You may fix your apostrophe/single-quote issue and find that the value you are concatenating is bringing in unexpected garbage that causes the SQL to fail.

Comment: yes, I will. I use parameters, here I didn't use them yet as I am testing the code.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
"INSERT INTO Product (UserId, Name) '" +
"'VALUES (null, '" + objProduct.Name + "');",
```

There are extra apostrophes: one at the end of the first line, one at the start of the second.

Also, use a parameter to avoid SQL injection attack, either intentionally or unintentionally. It could be causing your error, depending on what the value is in `objProduct.Name`.

Answer (score 1):

You have extra single quotes.  Your SQL query works out to `INSERT INTO Product (UserId, Name) ''VALUES (null, 'name')`